# "Error 1068 Dependency Service or Group Failed To Start"

Tags: windows, windows-xp

Why does "Error 1068 Dependency Service or Group Failed To Start" appear when starting the remote accessauto connection manager or print spooler in Windows XP?

Comment: What are the dependencies of this service?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a Lexmark printer by an chance? - There is a good description and solution for Windows XP related Error 1068 messages at the Microsoft Answers site - http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_xp-system/print-spooler-error-1068-the-dependency-service-or/399f0ba6-ee10-43b7-a51b-b30bebb56cd9

Depending on your environment and your type of printer installed, your Print Spooler Service will have other dependent services that must be running before the Print Spooler Service will start.  If the dependent services are not running, you will see an error 1068 or similar message about dependent services when trying to start the Print Spooler Service.

Some Lexmark printers will add their own services to XP and the starting of the Print Spooler Service lists them as dependencies and therefore those Lexmark Services must be running before the Print Spooler service will start.  It may be listed as the LexBce Server.

Do you now or have you ever had have any Lexmark printers installed?  If yes, are you still using the Lexmark printers?

Depending on your printing environment, if you are using another kind of printer, you may have other Service listed in the Dependencies tab of the Print Spooler Service.